Excel VBA to find/replace text in Word Document (255 character limit)
I'm trying to open a Word document, and then do find/replace to replace text that is in square brackets []. For the most part, this code works. But when I want to swap in a long sentence, I run against a character limit for ".Replacement.Text".
What is the simplest way to get around this limit? I looked at solutions involving copying to a clipboard, replacing the text with blank "" and inserting the text afterwards. But I do not know my away around Word documents in VB (activedocument, selections, story ranges...), and was unable to implement them.
'Open Word App
Dim wordApp As Object
Dim wordDoc As Object
Dim myStoryRange As Object

Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wordApp.Visible = False

'Open Table2.doc
Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(WIN_Path & "memo\table2_" & L_Effectivity & "_" & DEL_AIL & ".doc")

'Find/Replace using change_words
Dim myDict: Set myDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
myDict("[TABLE2_AUTHOR]") = Table2_Author
myDict("[JOB_NUMBER]") = Job_Number
myDict("[REGISTRATION]") = Registration
myDict("[EFFECTIVITY]") = Effectivity

For Each myStoryRange In wordDoc.StoryRanges
    For myLoop = 0 To myDict.Count - 1
        change_words myStoryRange, myDict.Keys()(myLoop), myDict.Items()(myLoop)
    Next
Next myStoryRange


Sub change_words(ByRef myStoryRange, ByVal findWord, ByVal replaceWord)
    With myStoryRange.Find
        .Text = findWord
        .Replacement.Text = replaceWord   '<<<<<<<CHARACTER LIMIT
        .Execute Replace:=2
    End With
End Sub



Replace the matched string one by one

Sub change_words(ByRef myStoryRange, ByVal findWord, ByVal replaceWord)
    With myStoryRange.Find
        .Text = findWord
'        .Replacement.Text = replaceWord   '<<<<<<<CHARACTER LIMIT
        Dim i As Long
        Do While .Execute And i < 2
            .Parent.Text = replaceWord
            .Parent.Collapse 0 ' Word.wdCollapseEnd
            i = i + 1
        Loop
    End With
End Sub

Dim destRange As Object
For Each myStoryRange In wordDoc.StoryRanges
    For myLoop = 0 To myDict.Count - 1
        Set destRange = myStoryRange.Duplicate
        change_words destRange, myDict.Keys()(myLoop), myDict.Items()(myLoop)
    Next
Next myStoryRange


Strangely, while the single replacement in the header and single replacement in the footer are populated, only the first replacement in the main body of the document gets replaced. I've tried shuffling around the order of the dictionary, but it is always the first replacement in the main body, and the rest are not replaced.

ByRef myStoryRange indicates that the argument is passed by reference. Any modifications made within the subprocedure (change_words) will affect myStoryRange in the calling subroutine. Try the update code.

On Set destRange = myStoryRange.Duplicate I get the error Run-time error '13', Type mismatch.

I forgot the code is run in Excel VBA. Try Dim destRange As Object.

Appreciate the help. It's almost there. There are multiple instances for some of the search terms. For example, multiple "[JOB_NUMBER]" fields that need to be replaced. Only the first instance is being replaced.

i is used as the count of replacement. i<2 means it replaces 2 instances (i=0 and i=1).

That's it! Thank you "taller"! I did notice it was running twice, so that makes ense. I ran it with i=1, and with i=10, and it runs so quickly that there was almost no performance impact.
